# What is 'fairness' in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, definitions

How does one define the concept of fairness in machine learning? I've seen the term lots of times but never used it myself in research ([1](https://fairmlbook.org/pdf/fairmlbook.pdf), [2](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3457607?casa_token=L1X2a8FI0SIAAAAA:xVo0kmwoeG6CtxW4faM2R_-5lNj0h6WXPqB1dp4YctON81ZIJNkJ9nOPGB7LNv7otWWhdpGRjs_z)). Is there a generally agreed-upon definition of fairness in machine learning? What are the different aspects of fairness? Or the intuition behind the concept of fairness?

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide 1-2 links/quotes that use this term. I've seen it in the context of explainable AI.

Answer (score 0):

The Ethical Guidelines for Trustworthy AI list four principles:

1. Respect for human autonomy
2. Prevention of harm
3. Fairness
4. Explicability

In fairness, two dimensions are considered.

> The substantive dimension implies a commitment to: ensuring equal and
> just distribution of both benefits and costs, and ensuring that
> individuals and groups are free from unfair bias, discrimination and
> stigmatisation. If unfair biases can be avoided, AI systems could even
> increase societal fairness. Equal opportunity in terms of access to
> education, goods, services and technology should also be fostered.
> Moreover, the use of AI systems should never lead to people being
> deceived or unjustifiably impaired in their freedom of choice.
> Additionally, fairness implies that AI practitioners should respect
> the principle of proportionality between means and ends, and consider
> carefully how to balance competing interests and objectives.
>
> The procedural dimension of fairness entails the ability to contest
> and seek effective redress against decisions made by AI systems and by
> the humans operating them. In order to do so, the entity accountable
> for the decision must be identifiable, and the decision-making
> processes should be explicable.

https://digital-strategy.ec.europa.eu/en/library/ethics-guidelines-trustworthy-ai

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question specifically mentioned Fairness in machine learning. How does this definition translate to definitions/applications in machine learning?

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn consider a ML system (e.g. classifier) used in banking to rank possibly bad future/current clients. You don't want such a system to base its predictions solely or mostly on features like gender, age, race, etc.

Comment: I understand the abstract definition and how i'd want my system to behave accordingly. But when can i say that my model is fair? Can i test it? Can i give my model incentives to converge to a 'fair' state? How is this incorporated into machine learning?